# Изменение значения вывода при клике на кнопке

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Вопрос такой. Есть app.component.html:

```
 <button id="btn_Discount"> Скидка </button>
 <div>    
  <ul>        
    <li *ngFor="let product of Products">            
      {{product.price + "грн."}}        
    </li>                      
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Нужно при клике на кнопке уменьшать значение product.price, например, product.price - 50. Нужно изменять значение только в представлении.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:
в app.component.ts

```
discount = 0
```

app.component.html

```
<button id="btn_Discount" (click)="discount = discount + 50"> Скидка </button>
 <div>    
  <ul>        
    <li *ngFor="let product of Products">            
      {{product.price - discount + "грн."}}        
    </li>                      
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо большое.